# Is it good idea to store whole xml file (.xml) document with tags in mongodb?

Tags: c#, xml, mongodb

Is it good idea to store whole xml file (.xml) document with tags in mongodb ?
Is there any risk?

If not then please help me to find the best way to persist the xml file on server?

Thanks.

Comment: Your post did not require an inline repetition of the title in heading style, so I removed it. Twice is enough.

Comment: Voted for closing. Although you already read the tour, you might want to do it again. You are not asking a specific coding question. The answer to this question is heavily opinion based, since you neither describe your use cases nor any other detail. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You could find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what you want to do with said XML document.

You can of course put an XML file as a string in a field of a MongoDB document. But in that case it will just be a text string full of funny `<` and  `>` characters.

That won't be a problem when you just want to store the document and later retrieve it based on meta-data you saved with the document.

But you will not be able to query by the content of said document or alter the document on the database alone. The only way to find a document by the XML content would be through a regular expression query, but these are quite slow and in most cases the XML document will be too complex to parse reliably with a regular expression.

When you want to store the XML document in a transparent way, you need to convert it to a BSON object first and then back to XML on retrieval, which will require some manual programming because these translations are not always unambiguous.

Alternatively you could use a database which supports XML natively, like some SQL databases do ([mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html), for example, but it's not the only one).